# Box, containing items with different rarity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have 4 different items with different "probability". The probability sets how often they should appear in the finalized outcome, on a large enough sample, for 42% rarity there should 42% of the overall supply of this item.

**These are the items and their respective points and probabilities:**

```
Common: Points - 100, Probability - 42%
Uncommon: Points - 140, Probability - 30%
Rare: Points - 210, Probability - 20%
Epic: Points - 525, Probability - 8%
```

I want to wrap them in boxes and I want each box to have MAX 765 points, not more. And put as many items as possible into each box, while maintaining the overall probability for each item.

**All possible box combinations:**

```
BOX 1       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
TOTAL   700

BOX 2       
Type    Points  Probability
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
TOTAL   700

BOX 3       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
TOTAL   760

BOX 4       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
TOTAL   720

BOX 5       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
TOTAL   680 

BOX 6       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
TOTAL   740 

BOX 7       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Rare    210 20%
Rare    210 20%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   730 

BOX 8       
Type    Points  Probability
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Rare    210 20%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   700 

BOX 9       
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Rare    210 20%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   760 

BOX 10      
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Rare    210 20%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   720 

BOX 11      
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   730 

BOX 12      
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Uncommon    140 30%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   690 

BOX 13      
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   750 

BOX 14      
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Rare    210 20%
TOTAL   710 

BOX 15      
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Uncommon    140 30%
Epic    525 8%
TOTAL   765

BOX 16
Type    Points  Probability
Common  100 42%
Common  100 42%
Epic    525 8%
TOTAL   725
```

**I am trying to find a way how to distribute these boxes randomly while keeping the overall probability of each item intact, respective to the overall supply.**

This is a solution I can think of:
I have pre-generated boxes (see above) and I would like to assign a probability to each box and distribute them based on that. But I have no idea how would I generate the probability of each box in order to keep the overall probabilities of the items intact. Let's say someone opens enough boxes to get 1000 items, there should be 420 commons, 300 uncommons, 200 rares and 80 epics. Any idea how to do it?

If my solution is wrong, please suggest different approach.

Comment: What does the rarity percentage mean here? Do you want that if someone opens a large amount of boxes, then on average, $42\%$ of all items are of common type, $30\%$ of all items are of uncommon type, etc?

Comment: I am not entirely clear about the problem, but it looks like some variation of the *knapsack problem* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @VTand On a large enough sample, for 42% rarity there should 42% of the overall supply of this type. Let's say someone opens enough boxes to get 1000 items, they should have 420 commons, 300 uncommons, 200 rares and 80 epics.

Comment: The question you are asking is not clear. Please rephrase

Comment: @Alborz rephrased the entire text, does it make more sense now?

Comment: @trueblueanil rephrased the text, does it make the problem clear?